# Secure Software Architecture

Tags: encryption, aes, sha, decryption

I am designing a software architecture and i need some suggestion and clarification on few issues.

This will be a server side RESTfull API for accessing data and multiple mobile/desktop client to access to API, collect some data and digital goods to consume in clients. It will be accessed over HTTPS

Clients will be iOS (Swift 2), Android (Java), Windows Phone (C#), Windows (C#), Windows Store (C#), Mac (Swift 2), Web (C#/JavaScript/HTML), Linux (Programming Language is not clear yet)

Server side applications programming language will be C# on .Net Framework 4.6 and it will run on Azure

Clients can be run on a Computer (MAC, PC, Linux), Browser, Smart phone or Tablet (iOS, Android, Windows Phone, Windows Store)

Clients will authenticate to REST service by using oAuth 2, then member will authenticate by using its username and password. Member Unique Id will be stored in client database to authenticate and request to API for the further steps/request since there will be no login required if member logs-out intentionally.

When member request from API there will be a download process for medium size digital files (like pdf or video files about 200 mb). Files will be encrypted on the server to decrypt on the client while it is consuming. That means we will decrypt digital products on runtime, so no file will be stored in the client decrypted. So my decryption must be very fast and low resource consuming but secure.

Members will be allowed to register -let’s say- 3 devices to use client software

Client devices will be registered automatically when member first use the app on the device.

Files needs to be consumed in the client if the client is registered, member is valid and digital product is bought by member. No other member or any other software will not be able to consume products.

Here is my initial approach to implement above requirements in the software so i can secure products and the system:

> I could not managed to enter all my explanations in here because form
>   was saying this is a spam. that is why i have add a link below so you
>   can find all my notes in there
>
> https://cryptbin.com/EDu#716f72dbd22ede12531a83cba4e464fb

---

### Here my questions;

- I will keep my members password in database with SHA-512 hash. I will use SALT for password. So i will keep SALT keys in database for each member. Is it safe and ok to implement that way?
- Should i keep IV (Initialization Vector) in the database for each product so i can use it for encryption? If so i need to expose it via my API so client can obtain it to decrypt. Is it safe to expose?
- Which encryption and Hashing algorithm is best to use in different environment without any problem. I will decrypt files in iOS, Android, Windows Phone, Windows, Mac etc. All native I know it from a friend that he used AES-128 and MD5 on server to encrypt but he face lots of problem on different clients when tried to decrypt files.
- I am planning to use AES-256 (Cipher Mode: CBC, Padding Mode: PKCS7, with IV) and SHA-512. Any comment on this choices?
- I will store 2 different Validation Password and 2 different Encryption password in database so i can use it with AES and SHA-512. But i need to store same passwords in the client code as hardcoded text so i can decrypt product. But this password can be stolen by de-obfuscating it. What is the best way keep this 4 password in the client environment as well as other important client information?
- When i publish iOS, Android and Windows Phone, Windows Store, Mac apps to the markets then they are getting obfuscated and signed automatically. I will manually sign and obfuscate my Windows Application. Is it enough to protect my code against curious people?
- I am using some data to encrypt or hash files or information. I have to expose that data over API so my clients can obtain it and use them for decryption. Is it safe to do it? Is there any other way to do it?
- Any suggestion on the architecture i explain above? Do you predict any kind of vulnerability on the approach?

*PS: I can give more details if we need to clarify anything.*

Comment: By and large the StackExchange model is more focused on the ability to provide complete and specific answers to specific questions. You've rolled up quite a lot into this one post. You may have better luck getting higher quality answers if you split it up into a number of smaller chunks.

Answer (score 1):

> I will keep my members password in database with SHA-512 hash. I will
> use SALT for password. So i will keep SALT keys in database for each
> member. Is it safe and ok to implement that way?

Yes, if you are using salt (which you should) then you should store the salt (in the clear) alongside the hash.

> Should i keep IV (Initialization Vector) in the database for each
> product so i can use it for encryption? If so i need to expose it via
> my API so client can obtain it to decrypt. Is it safe to expose?

It depends on what encryption scheme / mode you are using, but since you mentioned AES-CBC, there is no requirement to keep the IV secret. The only requirement is that the IV be random / unpredictable.

> Which encryption and Hashing algorithm is best to use in different
> environment without any problem. I will decrypt files in iOS, Android,
> Windows Phone, Windows, Mac etc. All native I know it from a friend
> that he used AES-128 and MD5 on server to encrypt but he face lots of
> problem on different clients when tried to decrypt files.

Encryption and hashing algorithms are language and OS agnostic, you should be able to find implementations in most languages. AES and the SHA family are especially well supported and widely used. I'm not sure what problems your friend is encountering (and generally you'll want to avoid MD5).

> I am planning to use AES-256 (Cipher Mode: CBC, Padding Mode: PKCS7,
> with IV) and SHA-512. Any comment on this choices?
>
> I am using some data to encrypt or hash files or information. I have
> to expose that data over API so my clients can obtain it and use them
> for decryption. Is it safe to do it? Is there any other way to do it?

I'm going to combine these two points. I'm going to assume when you say AES-256 and SHA-512 you mean AES for encryption and SHA as an integrity check for the message. There's a problem with this: say you encrypt the message and then compute the hash for integrity. Given that you are using CBC mode an adversary can (for example) do a [bit flipping attack](http://swepssecurity.blogspot.com/2014/05/bypassing-encrypted-session-tokens.html) and then recompute the hash of the modified ciphertext and you would be none the wiser. In general you would want to use a keyed hash (like HMAC) for integrity and authenticity.

Now (and to your second point), there's something called [Authenticated Encryption with Additional Data (AEAD)](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Erogaway/papers/ad.pdf) which will actually take care of the problems addressed in the previous paragraph (will provide confidentiality, integrity and authenticity without having to construct a scheme from primitives). It will also allow that some data (the additional data) be kept in the clear, but will still ensure the integrity of that data. Look into GCM mode (e.g. AES-GCM).

> I will store 2 different Validation Password and 2 different
> Encryption password in database so i can use it with AES and SHA-512.
> But i need to store same passwords in the client code as hardcoded
> text so i can decrypt product. But this password can be stolen by
> de-obfuscating it. What is the best way keep this 4 password in the
> client environment as well as other important client information?

I'm not an expert in this regard but it I would highly advise against hardcoding a password into the client. Any reasonably clever attacker will be able to recover this password in minimal time, so there's really no security gained here.

> When i publish iOS, Android and Windows Phone, Windows Store, Mac apps
> to the markets then they are getting obfuscated and signed
> automatically. I will manually sign and obfuscate my Windows
> Application. Is it enough to protect my code against curious people?

My understanding is that signing code / an app is to prove the authenticity of the code to the end user, so as to ensure that an adversary has not backdoored the code /app they downloaded or something along those lines, and not to make decompiling / reverse engineering more difficult. Obfuscation may also not be enough to keep a dedicated adversary from figuring out how your source works or recovering sensitive data in your code. It has always struck me as a case of [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

Answer (score 0):

The other answer, covers the bulk of the question, but the title is "secure software architecture", so I will answer this final broad question

> This will be a server side RESTfull API for accessing data and
> multiple mobile/desktop client to access to API
> ...

> Any suggestion on the architecture i explain above? Do you predict any
> kind of vulnerability on the approach?

There is a clear vulnerability.

When you have **humans writing custom code** in between the public web and your internal systems, you increase the risk of a security bug. The most common problem is SQL-Injection, but the problems go further than that. An API endpoint might not have authorisation set-up enabling an unauthorised user to do something that they shouldn't. If you want to check that authorisations are enforced correctly, you need to use a specialist software engineer to do that checking. You can certainly mitigate the bulk of the risks, but that comes at great cost, and doesn't eliminate the risks. Also, code changes over time, and so do developer teams.

So how do you accomplish an API without custom human-written code? With a database gateway. A popular example of this is GraphQL. It's a general-purpose tool, there is "custom code" but it's managed and maintained by the team who built the GraphQL server engine you choose. If there's a known vulnerability with processing JWTs, they will patch it. Not only do you get better security, but you also save time/money.

The idea of a "database gateway" doesn't have to be GraphQL either. It's possible to use SQL directly using the same pattern - see https://colossal.gitbook.io/microprocess/definition/data-web-gateway (I am an author of this draft open document)